Tokens with onchain data
I am wondering if it is possible to craft a type of token which seems to be a mix of existing existing standards. I cant seem to find it in any documentation. For reference, it is probably similar to ERC-1155.
I need 2 fields of metadata to be onchain (like token2022 metadata extension "additionalMetadata" field) so that the metadata can be read by an onchain (native Rust) program. I also need each token to have different metadata (again like "additionalMetadata"), but I also want each token to have the same mint address (like normal SPL token). How can I attach onchain data to tokens (with 0 decimals so they act like NFTs)?

for ERC 1155, you can take a look at the Fungible Assets standard from Metaplex,
Creating such assets would look like this
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, some } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { createFungibleAsset } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createFungibleAsset(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My Fungible Asset',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-fungible-asset.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
  decimals: some(7) // for 0 decimals use some(0)
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

Depending on what you need the metadata stores most of the information on-chain. Here is what the Metadata account contains https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/accounts/struct.Metadata.html
However, if it is paramount to use token-22, then I think you will need to add support for it as it isn't supported natively.
Also, note that you cannot use the metadata extension together with Metaplex, ref https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/token-2022#default-extensions
